# Getting a library to import properly in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, shared-libraries

So I want to mess around with a library I just downloaded called `stdlib.jar` (downloaded from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/)

So I added the library to the project, and when I inspect the project it looks like this in netbeans:
[image: package inspector in netbeans]

So it seems that the library is set up properly.

But then in my project when I try to use one of the library classes, it looks like this.

[image: My Custom Audio Player Class]

Mousing over the import statement at the top, says  `expected "."` 
And If I change the import statement to say `import stlib.StdAudio`  it says that the library does not exist.

Any body know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the source code of this library (which is pretty unusual: first time I encountered this) is in the default package, which means you don't have to import anything **if your class is also in the default package**. Just use the class name.

```
StdAudio.play(tone);
```

Just make sure it is in the classpath, but I think it is if I look at your screenshot from NetBeans.

---

**Update**: It seems like I'm wrong. At the bottom of the page, you can find this:

> **Q.** If I use a named package to structure my code, the compiler can no
>   longer access the libraries in `stdlib.jar`. Why not?
>   **A.** The libraries
>   in stdlib.jar are in the "default" package. *In Java, you can't access
>   classes in the default package from a named package.* If you need to
>   use our standard libraries with a named package, you must put our
>   libraries in a package, as in this solution.

So, you have to copy the classes into your project its package `musicplayer`.

Comment: Oh, that seems so messy. Haha, Ill just do that I guess. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

1) Get rid of the import statement.

2) Get rid of the package statement.

3) Put musicplayer.java  directly in the folder /src

4)Right click on libraries in the project menu and add stdlib.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Sedgewick textbook or Algorithms course on Coursera, this may be of help.

As it was mentioned above, the libraries in stdlib.jar are in the DEFAULT PACKAGE. In Java, you can't access classes in the default package from a named package. 
So you have to move your source files to a DEFAULT PACKAGE of your project. It means that you have to move your source musicplayer.java file from the ./src/MUSICPLAYER/ folder directly to the ./src folder of your project, then delete the MUSICPLAYER folder. Also you have to delete the "package MUSICPLAYER;" statement at the beginning of your source file(s).

Basically that's all you need to do.  Now when you moved your source file(s) to the default package, and added "stdlib.jar" to Libraries, you would have no problem addressing the classes from the library. You don't need no "import" statment for them.

Comment: stdlib is now included in algs4.jar which might be downloaded from here http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/code/