# Why won't StdDraw get recognized no matter what?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jar

I tried in two popular IDEs, eclipse and netbeans, to import a jar file named stdlib which contains a bunch of stuff. StdDraw is part of it but even after referencing it, the IDEs keep telling me it doesn't exist when I use their methods.

I have browsed stackoverflow and read other questions/answers and followed instructions to the letter. So why is this not working?

Comment: Excellent. Please add it as an answer and I will give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That jar file puts classes in the default package. ( a terrible idea)

To use it you have two options:

1. Put all of your files that access it in the default package
2. Use the alternative version of the library (http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib-package.jar)

See [Adding Default Package's Classes in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066600/adding-default-packages-classes-in-netbeans)